# Cassandra data modeling query

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql

Im currently learning apache cassandra and im new in nosql data modeling. At the moment im trying to build a system where i have the following fields:

```
 latitude | time_forecast       | longitude  | forecast_request | rh                 | swflx              | temp
----------+---------------------+------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------
    41.45 | 2016-04-26 17:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 | 0.6161368489265442 |  397.4789733886719 | 290.44512939453125
    41.45 | 2016-04-26 18:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 |  0.673031210899353 |  261.1000061035156 |  289.3315734863281
    41.45 | 2016-04-26 19:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 | 0.8489508032798767 | 27.700000762939453 |  286.8634948730469
    41.25 | 2016-04-26 17:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 | 0.6555368900299072 |  395.1789855957031 |  289.8011169433594
    41.25 | 2016-04-26 18:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 | 0.7271312475204468 | 203.39999389648438 |  288.5975646972656
    41.25 | 2016-04-26 19:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 | 0.8572507500648499 | 30.989999771118164 |  286.7254943847656
   41.456 | 2016-04-26 17:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 | 0.6161368489265442 |  397.4789733886719 | 290.44512939453125
   41.456 | 2016-04-26 18:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 |  0.673031210899353 |  261.1000061035156 |  289.3315734863281
   41.456 | 2016-04-26 19:00:00 | -8.6166667 |  2016-04-26_0000 | 0.8489508032798767 | 27.700000762939453 |  286.8634948730469
```

This is how i created the table:

```
create table if not exists forecast 
(   
    latitude varchar,
    longitude varchar,
    time_forecast varchar,
    forecast_request varchar,       
    swflx varchar,      
    temp varchar,
    rh varchar,

    PRIMARY KEY(latitude, time_forecast, longitude)
)

WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time_forecast ASC);
```

---

With this model , `time_forecast` cannot be my primary key because it will not be unique.

This was the only way i could insert data without making upserts but the problem im facing now is that i can't query the database only by `time_forecast`.

In this example, for each coordinate (latitude and longitude) im making a forecast for the next 3 hours and i can't avoid using a composite key.

**How would you model the database in a way i could retrieve the coordinates and variables from only a range of `time_forecast` value**?

Comment: Have you looked into the [timeuuid](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/uuid_type_r.html) data type? Using this type you can make your timestamps unique and use them as the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would you model the database in a way i could retrieve the coordinates and variables from only a range of time_forecast value?

```
create table if not exists forecast 
(   
    location text,
    latitude varchar,
    longitude varchar,
    time_forecast varchar,
    forecast_request varchar,       
    swflx varchar,      
    temp varchar,
    rh varchar,

    PRIMARY KEY((location), time_forecast)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time_forecast ASC);
```

Then you can query by range of time_forecast:

```
SELECT * FROM forecast
WHERE location = 'California'
AND time_forecast >= 'xxx' 
AND time_forecast <= 'yyy';
```

Comment: Yes good solution! If i would want to search by a specific latitude or longitude i guess i would have to build another table? Do you think?

Comment: Yes, to search by latitude or longitude you can:1) denormalize manually with another table 2) Use materialized views for automatic denormalization

Comment: This is very powerful stuff. May i ask you, between InfluxDB or Cassandra, personally what would you pick to handle massive amounts of data, basically time series weather forecasts?